# Kubernetes cluster Mysql Nodes Storage

Tags: kubernetes

We have started setting up a Kubernetes cluster. On Production, we have 4 Mysql Nodes(2 Active Master, 2 Active slaves). Complete servers are on-premise, There is NO cloud providers usage.

Now how do I configure storage? I mean should I use PV / PVC? How will it work. Should I use local PV? Can someone explain to me this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [PersistentVolumes and PersistentVolumeClaims](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) in order to achieve that.

> A PersistentVolume (PV) is a piece of storage in the cluster that has
>   been provisioned by an administrator or dynamically provisioned using
>   Storage Classes.
>
> A PersistentVolumeClaim (PVC) is a request for storage by a user.
>   Claims can request specific size and access modes (e.g., they can be
>   mounted once read/write or many times read-only).

Containers are ephemeral. When the container is restarted all the changes made prior to it are lost. Databases, however expect the data is persistent, therefore you need persistent volumes. You have to create a storage claim and the pod must be configured to mount the claimed storage.

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-single-instance-stateful-application/) you will find a simple guide showing how to deploy MySQL with a PersistentVolume. However, I strongly recommend getting familiar with the official docs that I have linked in order to fully understand the concept and adjust the access mode, class, size, etc according to your needs.

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But what I want to ask is what type of PV should I use? Is it local which ensures pod will rerun on same node in case of update. Plus how do we ensure running pod on specific nodes only(using taints?).  We are not using any cloud storage. So the storage and pods needs to be on same node . Plus we have 4 mysql pod cluster whicg we want to run on 4 different node(for redundancy). So mysql data needs to be present on that 4 nodes. Then we need to ensure pod rund in those nodes only(may be using taints and node affinity). Example mentioned in doc is single node cluster.

Comment: "how do we ensure running pod on specific nodes only" - by using one of [these methods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/) or [NodeAffinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#node-affinity) as you mentioned you want to use local storage.

Comment: As for the PV type, Network File System (NFS) is a standard protocol that lets you mount a storage device as a local drive. And if you want your data to be accessible on all 4 nodes than you should use access mode of `ReadWriteMany` which you are allowed to with NFS. I hope this helps and that I have understood you correctly. If not, please let me know, we can analyze your use-case further.